# JWT Authentication in salesforce

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am trying to log in another user in my same org using below code.

```
String username = 'test1@salesforce.com';
String jwtVal = '*****';

String tokenEndPoint = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()+'/services/oauth2/token';
System.debug('::::tokenEndPoint:::'+tokenEndPoint);

Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
jwt.setSub(username);                          //Set the subject claim in the JWT using the username
jwt.setAud('https://test.salesforce.com');     //Set the base URL as the audience claim in the JWT            
jwt.setIss(jwtVal);                            //Set the issuer claim in the JWT using OAuth2 client id
Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'jwtapp');    //Sign the JWT bearer token using the digital signature

System.debug('JWS:: '+jws);

String token = jws.getCompactSerialization();    //Get the resulting JWS 

System.debug(':::token::: ' + token);

Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndPoint, jws);    //POST the JWT bearer token to the SF token endpoint
String accToken = bearer.getAccessToken();
```

But, I got the below error in *jws.getCompactSerialization()* line.

> System.NoDataFoundException: Data Not Available: The data you were
>   trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user
>   deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not
>   deleted but cannot access it, please look at our page

Comment: Your example username indicates this is for a production org, but you're using `test.salesforce.com` as the `aud` in your JWT claims. Is that on purpose, or just an artifact of making your code ok to share with us? I don't think it's the source of _this_ particular error, but it'll likely be an issue later on.

Comment: @MSCB I would like to know the solution for the above issue. Facing the same issue as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It can't find your `jwtapp` keypair or you don't have permissions to see it:

```
Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'jwtapp')
```

Confirmed that this is the root cause by running your code with a valid keypair.

Comment: Hi, I have a question on setting up the "certdevname".  How do you set up the 'jwtapp'?  Is it a Self Signed Certificate? Or an import from keystore?  Where in the process do we use the private key from the external app?

Comment: @chynadoll If the private key is generated outside of Salesforce, then the only way to import it is via the keystore.