# JWT - loading a private key from Certificates and Key Management

Tags: apex, jwt

I am trying to use JWT and I am getting error at jws.getCompactSerialization(); What am I missing.

BOXJWT is Selfsign certificate.

```
Map<String, String> extraClaims= new Map<String,String>();
        extraClaims.put('box_sub_type', 'enterprise');
        Auth.Jwt jwt = new Auth.Jwt();
        jwt.setIss('y2vb52kd5zoygueyyxXXXXXXXXXX'); 
        jwt.setAud('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token');
        jwt.setSub('33XXXXXX'); //enterpriseId of my box.com account
        jwt.setAdditionalClaims(extraClaims);
        jwt.setValidityLength(60);

        Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'BOXJWT'); 
        String assertion = jws.getCompactSerialization();
```

**ERROR:**

> Line: 108, Column: 1 System.NoDataFoundException: Data Not Available:
> The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due
> to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the
> data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

[image]

**Certificate Details:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT Authentication in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271038/jwt-authentication-in-salesforce)

Comment: @identigral not really, I have already seen this, BOXJWT is a certificate not connected app, how do we give access to certificate, I don't see any options

Comment: `Customize Application` is the profile permission to edit/create/manage certs. That's more than just reading the cert but it's enough to diagnose an issue with perms. The other, more likely possibility is that the `Unique Name` on your cert is not `BOXJWT`.

Comment: @identigral - I checked the permission, the profile has the permission and also Unique Name is corrected as you it shows in the screenshot. what else am missing here?

Comment: The only other thing is Execute Anon - try invoking your code via another pathway such as a REST API. If that doesn't work, open a case with SF.